# asterisk send caller id to http

Tags: php, asterisk

in my LAN i do have a PC that runs asterisk. in a second PC i do have a PHP application. Up to now i have seen that there are ready solutions such as Elastix with CRM, but it does not meet my requirements.

i do need to send the caller id from asterisk to php, or have the php to pull the callers id everytime the when the call is comes to asterisk. How do i manage this task? is there any tool ready for this job? i would prefer to have the php to pul the call details from the asterisk server.

Answer (score 0):

There is AMI protocol you can use to read events.

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4817239

There are some solutions, for example FOP2 from asternic